# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED only on a certain internet connection

Tags: networking, dns, webserver, website

I am hosting `georgikarapetrov.xyz` with IP 83.228.117.132 on Raspberry Pi, sitting behind a generic ZTE router. Port forwarding is set.

People can see the website useing internet connections from providers other than mine.

I cannot see the website using my ISP's connection and neither can my ISP support. On Brave browser the error is `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`, on Firefox it is `Address Not Found`. `nslookup georgikarapetrov.xyz` gives the right IP. At the same time, I can see the website on the same device through other internet connections.

My IPS claims the issue cannot possibly have anything to do with them. My registrar sees no issues with the DNS records.

What can I do to debug this? How could my set up cause it? Can I look for evidence to suggest to my ISP to do something at their side?

Please, let me know if I any logs, configurations or other information would be useful.

(I don't have NAT loopback on my router so I can only test on my phone using the mobile internet connection. The phone has Nethunter but it's not rooted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your nameservers, `ns3.epik.com` and `ns4.epik.com`, appears to have two IPv4 addresses – for each nameserver, one address is working as intended but the other is ignoring almost all DNS-over-UDP requests.

- `ns3.epik.com`

  - `52.55.168.70` – works properly
  - `144.217.90.42` – ignores most UDP queries
- `ns4.epik.com`

  - `172.107.216.250` – works properly
  - `144.217.90.42` – ignores most UDP queries

(Notice that both names actually have the same 2nd address. That's something the DNS provider shouldn't be doing...)

So I'm guessing that your DNS resolver tries the bad address for ns3, then tries the same bad address for ns4, and eventually gives up due to timeout.